# The girl who lives vs the girl who live

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

should we add the letter s in the word "live"when it is used it the phrase "the girl who live "?
Which one is right?

Answer (score -2):

Add -s to the verb when the subject is singular:

> The girl who lives
>
> The girls who live

Comment: So I should say: I lives in France ?
:'p

Comment: Methinks you should change "singular" to "third party singular in the simple present tense".